# Why in HL pair, H is stored after L register

Tags: 8085

Why in 8085, during `LHLD` and `SHLD` instructions L is used first while in `BC` and `DE`, B and D are used respectively?

Comment: Might have something to do with the endianness.

Comment: @Gowtham: on what evidence do you base your assumption?

Comment: From reading the [Wikipedia article on the 8085](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8085#16-bit_operations) it seems you cannot directly store BC and DE to RAM.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen that's the thing given in my book and in internet.

Comment: @starblue you're right.

Answer (score 3):

The 8085 has seven internal 8-bit registers for data, called A, B, C, D, E, H, and L. Six of these registers can also be used in pairs to hold 16-bit quantities. These pairs are BC, DE and HL, where B, D and H hold the MSB of the value and C, E and L hold the LSB, respectively.

When these register pairs are transferred to/from memory, the LSB is always stored in the lower address and the MSB in the upper. The `SHLD` and `LHLD` instructions can be used to transfer the HL pair to/from an arbitrary address, while the `PUSH` and `POP` instructions can transfer any of the three pairs to/from the stack.

I hope this answers your question. I'm not sure what you mean when you say L is "used first".

Comment: And this historical fact is why the PC is a little-endian machine. The modern PC's x86 architecture is the 32-bit expansion of a 16-bit expansion of the 8085. The 8085 is a cleanup of the 8080, which was a huge jump in function from the 8008, which was in some ways an 8-bit expansion of the 4004. Which is in many ways the first CPU in a chipset.

Comment: A bit more information on the history. The Datapoint 2200 was a "programmable terminal" with a processor built from a board full of TTL chips. The Intel 8008 was created to duplicate and replace this processor board. Since the Datapoint 2200 had an 8-bit serial processor operating on one bit at a time, it had to start with the lowest bit first to handle arithmetic. This made the Datapoint 2200 little endian. The 8008 copied this, and its descendants were  also little endian (as @RBerteig describes). Despite the similar names, the 8008 is unrelated to the 4004 architecturally.

Answer (score 1):

On the 8085, there probably isn't any particular advantage to having 16-bit operations act on the low byte before the high byte, though having the operation which acts upon the lower address precede the one which acts upon the higher address may allow the address of the second byte to be computed while the first byte is being processed.  On some other processors like the 6502, however, there is a definite advantage to having data stored LSB first.  If one performs an instruction like: "$ABCD: LDA ($12),Y", Y holds the value $A0, and locations $12 and $13 hold the values $56 and $34, respectively, the sequence of operations will be:

```
$ABCD : $A1  -- Load opcode
$ABCE : $12  -- Load operand (pointer address)
$0012 : $56 Load LSB of target base address while adding 1 to pointer address
$0013 : $34 Load MSB of target address while adding Y register to LSB (yields $F6)
$34F6 : Data -- Load data while adding one to MSB
```

Note that the result of adding one to the MSB of the address is ignored, but the instruction loads A from an address taken by adding an 8-bit register to a pair of bytes in memory, in five cycles, which is the least it could possibly take.  Note also that the processor must always know a cycle in advance where the upper and lower halves of the next address are going to come from.  Had the Y register held $B0 instead of $A0, the sequence would have been:

```
$ABCD : $A1  -- Load opcode
$ABCE : $12  -- Load operand
$0012 : $56 Load LSB of target base address while adding 1 to pointer address
$0013 : $34 Load MSB of target address while adding Y register to LSB (yields $06)
$3406 : Data -- Load data while adding one to MSB
$3506 : Data -- Load data
```

In this case, the upper half of the correct address ($3506) won't be the value fetched from memory, but will be based upon data which isn't available before the read of $0013.  Further, the bus-interface logic needs to know what it's supposed to do before it knows whether or not adding the Y register to the target LSB will yield a carry.  Consequently, the system will perform a read of the address formed by taking the just-computed LSB and the just-fetched MSB, without regard for whether the address is correct.  It will then during the read discover that the address was incorrect, and repeat the read with an adjusted address MSB.

The fact that the 6502 uses LSB-first addressing means that although six cycles will be required in the situation where the address LSB computation yields a carry, only five will be needed in cases where it does not.  If code and data are arranged so as to avoid indexing across page boundaries, it will be possible to save a cycle in most cases.  If addresses were stored MSB first, an extra cycle would always be required.  Incidentally, when performing a "STA" rather than "LDA", the processor will always do a read of the first-computed address (which may or may not be correct) and ignore the result, and follow that with a write of the guaranteed-correct address.  During that read, the processor will use the ALU to add 1 to the MSB of the address whether or not there was a carry from the LSB [as opposed to either adding 0 or 1, based upon the carry].  There's a pattern of bits which would seem like it should represent the opcode "STX ($12),Y", but its meaning is undefined.  What that bit pattern actually does is store the value of X, ANDed with the MSB of the address plus 1, to an address which is either correct (if there was no carry from the LSB), or has its MSB equal to the AND of the correct address and the content of the X register.  Essentially, X and the ALU are both being gated onto the same bus, and that value on that bus holds the data to be stored and sometimes the address MSB as well.