# Correct representation of a number

Tags: digital-logic

Let us consider we have a number 011100010.Suppose we are storing this number in an 8 bit system.So how will it be stored from left to right like 01110001 or the rightmost 8 digits and leaving the first bit out like 11100010.Why or why not?

Comment: Totally depends on what kind of system, what "storing this number" exactly means, are we talking about vhdl, C, assembly ... ?

Comment: is the MSB ever going to be set (signed or unsigned). if no... store as 8bit, if yes... well...

Comment: @MaximGi,we are talking about an 8085 system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the subject of [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

There is no *right* or *wrong* way to store data, provided it is done consistently in a given platform.

As alluded to by JonRB, the most significant bit can have meaning (as indeed can any bit in a bit stream), but provided it is always stored in the same manner (so the platform can always access this bit in the same manner regardless of which data it may exist in) it is not really of any consequence.

When transferring data from one type of system to another is when interesting things *can* happen.

The 8085 is a [little endian](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/85560/why-in-hl-pair-h-is-stored-after-l-register) device.

Comment: @user1369975: For processors, yes, but this is more by convention than definition. The bit order can be in either direction (again, if it is consistent) but will normally logically flow in the direction of bit order. Look up 'PDP-endian' for an interesting implementation.

Comment: So this means decimal representation should be -30

Answer (score 0):

8 bit numbers are stored in 8 bits.  Somewhere there will be 8 flip-flops or memory cells that can either be set to 0 or 1.

It seems you are really asking about text representation of this to humans.  That's a whole different can of worms.  However, in the arabic numbering systems, digits are written in most to least significant order, left to right.  Therefore leading zeros don't change the value of a number and can be removed.  Your nine-digit binary number "011100010" can just as well be written as 8 digits as "11100010".

The rules aren't different just because you are using a different number base than ten.  This same value can be expressed as E2 in hexadecimal, 342 in octal, or 226 in decimal.  If you were counting people walking into a building with a 4 digit counter and it read "0226", you would likely write that down as 226 people entered the building because you know "0226" and "226" mean the same thing.

There is one wrinkle to this, especially in binary.  There is more than one way to use a sequence of bits (binary digits) to represent a value.  For example, your 8 bit byte could be *unsigned* or *signed twos complement*.  In unsigned format, 11100010 is just 226 in decimal.  However, in twos complement format, the 8 bits represent values from -128 to +127.  In that case, 11100010 means decimal -30, but 011100010 has a 0 sign bit so means 226 decimal.

Comment: ,so considering the two's complement system,the answer should be -30